# add physics between children of skspritenode

Tags: ios, resize, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

[image: World explanation]

**World explanation:**
All balls are moving around slowly and can collide with each other/the frame.

**Ball explanation:**
Each ball contains a number of images, moving around and can collide like the balls can do, with the ball as a frame.

You can add new balls and new images. There is **the problem:**

Every ball/image should be **resizable**. (ball depending on the containing images).

As you can't resize physics body in Sprite Kit, i have to scale e.g. a ball with SKAction scaleBy: .. But then, the containing images will be scaled too.

My solution:
Adding a child-SKSpriteNode *physicsNode (invisible) to every ball/image and while i resize the ball/image with SKAction resizeBy: , i SKAction scaleBy: the child-physicsNode.

But now, i can't add forces to the physicsBody of physicsNode, because it got the same size of the parent ball/image.

Does anyone get a better solution?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does scaleBy really scale the physics bodies as well, have you tried? It certainly didn't work in iOS 7(.0). Also bodies contained within other bodies is not possible or at least very tricky. The enclosing body would have to be either a static (edge-based) body and thus wouldn't react to forces, or the bodies inside the enclosed bodies would have to be simply stopped when they reach the enclosing body's bounds using a regular distance check (physics can't help here).

Comment: yes, i've tried it: When e.g. a ball collide with another ball while SKAction scaleBy: they are moving each other away without overlapping. 
This behavior is ideal, excepting, that the childs are scaled as well.

Comment: maybe i can create a SKScene in every ball and resize this SKScene after scaling?

Comment: Nope. You can only have one active SKScene. The others won't run their physics and updates. At least last time I tried.